# Need suggestion about java thread pool execution queue processing

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat7, threadpoolexecutor

- In my application we have number of clients Databases, every hour we
  get new data for processing in that databases
- There is a cron to checks data from this databases and pickup the data and
- Then Create thread pool and It start execution of 30 threads in parallel and 
  remaining thread are store in queue
- it takes several hours to process this all threads
- So while execution, if new data arrives then it has to wait, because this cron 
  will not pickup this newly arrived data until it's current execution is not 
  got finished.
- Sometimes we have **priority data for processing** but due to this case that 
  clients also **need to wait for several hours** for processing their data.

**Please give me the suggestion to avoid this wait state for newly arrived data**

(I am working on java 1.7 , tomcat7 and SQL server2012)

Thank you in advance
Please let me know, for more information on this if not clear

Comment: Seems like you need separate thread pools for the two types of jobs. Any problem with that?

Comment: are you creating a new thread pool every time your process runs? why not just reuse the existing pool. maybe you are low on memory and that is why it takes so long to process everything

Comment: also why are you passing data around by database access instead of a service (ie a rest based service (if you have any control over that))

Comment: Ernest Kiwele we have no problem with your solution but i am try to get any another solution. John Kane Pool is handle by cron, so it create new pool, if cron's previous work got finished and we cant use web service for this task its already define for database.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your thread should procces data in bulk (for example 100/1000 records) and this records should be selected from DB by priority. Each time you select new records for proccesing data with highest priority go first.

I can't create comment yet :(

Comment: Currently there is not priority but sometimes its happens that client required processed data ASAP. so due to this pooling and queuing it get delayed

Comment: How do you know which data have to be processed ASAP?

Comment: We take data in hashmap and then give it to thread pool. after that it depends on thread pool how it will schedule threads for processing

Comment: IMHO I changed process of data processing. Now you load all you data and than you use 30 thread to process data. Why can not every thread load data which will be process by him. So transaction boundaries are load data -> process data -> save data and i case off problem only this data will be rollbaked

Comment: Okay,thank you. I got your point, i will think on your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, if you will load data partially your memory requirements will be lower, Your onethread can process normal data and data with hight priority (no other pools are required) and only on amout of data for single run depends when new data will be load. So you can tune your system only by adding/removing number of thread and amount of data. And if yoy need more power you can make cluster where same application will be used.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem we are thinking about two solution

1. Create more then one thread pool for processing normal and high
   priority data.
2. Create more then one tomcat instance with same code for processing normal and priority 
   data

**But I am not understanding which solution is best for my case 1 or 2**

Please give me suggestions about above solutions, so that i can take decision on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool()`

**Benefits of using a cached thread pool :**

The pool creates new threads if needed but reuses previously constructed threads if they are available.

Only if no threads are available for reuse will a new thread be created and added to the pool.

Threads that have not been used for more than sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache. Hence a pool which has not been used long enough will not consume any resources.